# How can I get the timestamp from a `rtspsrc` header with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I need to get to the the timestamp from a rtp source. The timestamp is stored in the header:

[image]

For now, I can record the stream using the following command,

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://<url> ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

I have no idea how to access the header from the command-line.